# How I can get db's current restore mdoe status by query?

Tags: sql, restore, log-shipping

So, my db can be in three differrent statuses.

- RECOVERY
- NORECOVERY
- STANDBY

And I want to know current db's status by query. Can you help me ?
The single what I've found is

```
SELECT is_in_standby
     FROM sys.databases
WHERE [name] = 'MyDb1'
```

And If `MyDb1` is actually in `StandBy` mode I'll give following:

```
is_in_standby
-------------
1
```

But Is there way to determine that `MyDb1` in `NoRecovery` mode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally I've found out a solution. Actually it's a sort of merge two queries

```
SELECT 
    case
        when is_in_standby = 1 then N'YES'
        else 'NO'
    END as STANDBY
    , DATABASEPROPERTYEX ('MyDb1', 'Status') STATUS
FROM sys.databases
WHERE [name] = 'MyDb1'
```

Result

```
STANDBY STATUS
------- ------
YES     ONLINE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
SELECT rhistory.destination_database_name,rhistory.restore_date,
rhistory.destination_database_name,rhistory.user_name,
CASE 
WHEN rhistory.[recovery] = 0 THEN 'NoRecovery' 
WHEN sysdb.[is_in_standby] = 1 THEN 'StandBy'
ELSE 'Recovery' END AS Recovery_State
FROM msdb..restorehistory rhistory
INNER JOIN sys.databases sysdb ON sysdb.name=rhistory.destination_database_name
ORDER BY rhistory.restore_date DESC
```